# MauiFont not imported in net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 project

Tags: c#, fonts, maui, embedded-resource

A **.ttf** file that is designated `MauiFont` resource seems to import *automatically* for an iOS or Android project. What would it take to import **home.ttf** *manually* in order to make Windows recognize the font?

In the **Resources\Fonts** folder of my Maui app, there is a **home.ttf** where the **BuildAction** is set to **MauiFont**. I want to initialize the icons for the flyout items by doing something like this, which works in Android and iOS, but not in Windows.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(FlyoutText)))
    {
        var menuItem = new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.MenuItem { Text = name };

        menuItem.IconImageSource = new FontImageSource
        {
            FontFamily = "home",
            Glyph = "\uE800",
            Size = 75,
            Color = Colors.Black,
        };
        menuItem.Clicked += onFlyoutItemClicked;
        Shell.Current.Items.Add(menuItem);
    }
    Shell.Current.Items[0].IsVisible = false;
}
```

[image: android shows icon glyph- windows shows not-found placeholder]

---

With a `FontFamily` that is certain to be found, it can be demonstrated that the method works. What does Windows need to achieve the same objective of importing a custom font?

```
menuItem.IconImageSource = new FontImageSource
{
    FontFamily =  "Webdings",
    Glyph = "\u0048",
    Size = 75,
    Color = Colors.Black,
};
```

[image: windows success]

Comment: Have you got the correct parameters for the `fonts.AddFont()` in your `MauiProgram.cs` ?

Comment: Huh! No I do not! I'm afraid I wasn't aware of `fonts.AddFont()` this block until you pointed it out. Now that I am it sure makes sense to supply the correct code here. This is the kind of thing that comes with being new with the MAUI platform. Looks like the counterpart to statements like`[assembly: ExportFont("dbplus.ttf", Alias = "dbplus")]` in Xamarin perhaps? I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you register your font in `MauiProgram.cs`, i.e.

```cs
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                    fonts.AddFont("home.ttf", "home"); // <=  Add your font here
                });

            builder.Services.AddLocalization();

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
```