# How to use Path as ImageSource in Maui Button

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

We get .SVG files, where we get data in form of Geometry. We use ControlTemplate in WPF to give Geometry as Icon to buttons.

My question is:

I have a Path data like

```
<Geometry Data="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"/>
```

How to give this as Source to Button in Maui

Example:

```
<Button Source="?"/>
```

Expecting result to give geometry as ImageSource to button in Maui

Comment: Geometry Data="M21.."

Comment: It's not easy to transfer a Path data to ImageSource. I think one easy way is that adding a TapGesture on the Path control.

Answer (score 0):

You create static resources In you window or whereever you need them and then you reference them in a path in your button. As a next step you can put all this in a style or even attach a Geometry property to your button so you can set it directly, but this for now will do what you ask for.

```
   <Window.Resources>
      <Geometry Data="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z" x:Key="YourShape"/>                        
   </Window.Resources>

   <Button>
      <Path Data="{StaticResource YourShape}" Fill="HotPink"/>
   </Button>
```

(Thats a WPF Answer, never worked with Maui before, hope it still applies)

Comment: It doesnot work with Maui!!

Comment: It works in Debug mode and does not work in Release mode. I create a reproduction and bug report at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20552

Answer (score 0):

This "may or may not" work for your use case, but it's something that I definitely wish I had known about sooner. Sites like [Fontello](https://fontello.com/) allow you to import your **.svg** icons and consolidate them into a font.ttf file containing glyphs for your custom icons (and/or any of the standard icons they provide). When I imported my **parent-pin-collapsed.svg** file and exported to **my-svg-icons** here is the result.

[image: demo on Android]

Here's a brief overview of the process:

[image: roadmap]

---

**Xaml**

```xml
<!--So easy to make an icon-->
<Button
    x:Name="CounterBtn"
    Text="&#xE801;"
    FontFamily="my-svg-icons"
    Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
    HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Button.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="DarkBlue" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

---

**Importing the font**

*This honestly seems to be optional on platforms other than WinUI...*

Per [Stephen Quan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77278771/5438626) make sure you register your font in MauiProgram.cs, i.e.

```cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                fonts.AddFont("my-svg-icons.ttf", "my-svg-icons");
            });

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```